# TinyMCE: TypeError: K is undefined

Tags: jquery, tinymce, nullreferenceexception, typeerror

I've added a button to an existing plugin (the plugin works perfectly). The button dynamically creates a virtual keyboard `$('#vkb')` that lets users select some symbols. The first time that I execute that button on tinyMCE, it works, and I can select symbols and have them inserted into TinyMCE editor.

But then at some point in this first, correctly functioning instance, I get the error `TypeError: K is undefined`. The current instance continues to work, although calling ed.execCommand keeps bringing up the `K undefined` error. But after that, all other instances of creating a TinyMCE toolbar, the following happens:

1. `ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, str);` command in the
   plugin code does not work, and
2. this error shows up: `t is null` (where I think `t` is most likely `this`, i.e. the editor itself).

The following is my code:

```
      // Registering the command
       ed.addCommand('mceArIndic', function() {
       _dovkb();

    function _dovkb()
    {  // some code for a virtual keybaord that lets users choose indic symbols
           // the final symbols are stored in a variable called 'ret'
           // I want ret's contents to be inserted in the tinymce editor

           // the code below is what happens when the closing key on the virtual keyboard is clicked:

    $('#vkbstop').live('click',function(e){
    var ret = $('#numoutput').val();
    $('#numoutput').val('');
    $('#vkb').remove();
    console.log("t.inserting");
            /* THIS IS WHERE K SOMETIMES BECOMES UNDEFINED, THEN ALL */ 
            /* DYNAMICALLY-CREATED TINMYCE INSTANCES THAT FOLLOW HAVE T AS NULL */
    ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, ret); 
    toprint = '';
});

    // Register arindic button
    ed.addButton('arindic', {
        title : 'Type Arabic/Indic digits',
        cmd : 'mceArIndic',
        image : url + '/img/indic.png'
    });
```

At the end of the code the plugin is registered correctly.

I thought maybe the editor just hasn't finished loading, but that's not the case, because I've tried it after waiting for long delays as well. Why does `ed.execCommand` sometimes give that `K is null` error, and why after that do all attempts at the command just say that `t is null`, although it's not, because other buttons are working fine.

### Edit

After switching to tiny_mce_dev.js, it gave me a slightly different error, instead of "K", not it's "selection": 
`TypeError: selection is null` 
with a bit more info: 
`ieRng = selection.getRng();` - Editor.js line 897

Comment: I've noticed @Thariama seems to have good experience in TinyMCE... I hope you visit SO soon! Thanks.

Comment: can you include tiny_mce_dev.js instead of tiny_mce.js (?) (available through the tinymce developer download version). this will give some more usefull information regarding errors

Comment: I just downloaded the development package... but there's no jQuery version of this, and I've done development in jQuery.

Comment: you do not need the jQuery version of tinymce, it is better to load jQuery on the main page and use the regular tinymce build, jquery will be available through all tinymce applications/own plugins. the init looks a bit different, but the jQuery build causes several issues and is pretty slow (especially when it comes to keyboardi nput processing) due to the object creation overhead

Comment: I added the javascript dev version and tried it out. It gave me a slightly different error, instead of "K", not it's "selection": `TypeError: selection is null` with a bit more info: 
`ieRng = selection.getRng(); - Editor.js line 897`

Comment: ok, now, you put a console.trace () just before that line in the source code and we will get to know which line of code triggered that error- looks liek a race condition of some sort